# Update on key violation in Stored Procedure using BULK INSERT & Trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, bulkinsert

I have a stored procedure that performs a bulk insert of a large number of DNS log entries. I wish to summarise this raw data in a new table for analysis. The new table takes a given log entry for FQDN and Record Type and holds one record only with a hitcount.

Source table might include 100 rows of:

```
FQDN, Type
www.microsoft.com,A
```

Destination table would have:

```
FQDN, Type, HitCount
www.microsoft.com, A, 100
```

The SP establishes a unique ID made up of [FQDN] +'|'+ [Type], which is then used as the primary key in the destination table.

My plan was to have the SP fire a trigger that did an UPDATE...IF @@ROWCOUNT=0...INSERT. However, that of course failed because the trigger receives all the [inserted] rows as a single set so always throws a key violation error.

I'm having trouble getting my head around a solution and need some fresh eyes and better skills to take a look. The bulk insert SP works just fine and the raw data is exactly as desired. However trying to come up with a suitable method to create the summary data is beyond my present skills/mindset.

I have several 10s of Tb of data to process, so I don't see the summary as a something we could do dynamically with a SELECT COUNT - which is why I started down the trigger route.

The relevant code in the SP is driven by a cursor consisting of a list of compressed log files needing to be decompressed and bulk-inserted, and is as follows:

```
-- Bulk insert to a view because bulk insert cannot populate the UID field
SET @strDynamicSQL = 'BULK INSERT [DNS_Raw_Logs].[dbo].[vwtblRawQueryLogData] FROM ''' + @strTarFolder + '\' + @strLogFileName + ''' WITH (FIRSTROW = 1, FIELDTERMINATOR = '' '', ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0a'', ERRORFILE = ''' + @strTarFolder + '\' + @strErrorFile + ''', TABLOCK)'
--PRINT @strDynamicSQL
EXEC (@strDynamicSQL)

-- Update [UID] field after the bulk insert
UPDATE [DNS_Raw_Logs].[dbo].[tblRawQueryLogData]
    SET [UID] = [FQDN] + '|' + [Type]
    FROM [tblRawQueryLogData]
    WHERE [UID] IS NULL
```

I know that the UPDATE...IF @@ROWCOUNT=0...INSERT solution is wrong because it assumes that the input data is a single row. I'd appreciate help on a way to do this.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, at that scale make sure you understand [columnstore tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15).  They are very highly compressed and fast to scan.

Then write a query that reads from the raw table and returns the summarized

create or alter view DnsSummary
as
select FQDN, Type, count(*) HitCount
from tblRawQueryLogData
group by FQDN, Type

Then if querying that view directly is too expensive, write a stored procedure that loads a table after each bulk insert.  Or make the view into an [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer David, obvious when someone else looks at it!

I ran the view-based solution with 14M records (about 4 hours worth) and it took 40secs to return, so I think i'll modify the SP to drop and re-create summary table each time it runs the bulk insert.

The source table also includes a timestamp for each entry. I would like to grab the earliest and latest times associated with each UID and add that to the summary.

My current summary query (courtesy of David) looks like this:

```
SELECT [UID], [FQDN], [Type], COUNT([UID]) AS [HitCount]
    FROM [DNS_Raw_Logs].[dbo].tblRawQueryLogData
    GROUP BY [UID], [FQDN], [Type]
    ORDER BY COUNT([UID]) DESC
```

And returns:

```
UID, FQDN, Type, HitCount
www.microsoft.com|A, www.microsoft.com, A, 100
```

If I wanted to grab first earliest and latest times then I think I'm looking at nesting 3 queries to grab the earliest time (SELECT TOP N...ORDER BY... ASC), the latest time (SELECT TOP N...ORDER BY... DESC) and the hitcount. Is there a more efficient way of doing this, before I try and wrap my head around this route?